# How to create a new data frame using for loops and conditional statements

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a for loop wherein a new dataframe is created based on a conditional statement of a column, but all I end up with is are only the column names without any values.

What I am doing now is the following:

```
for i in range(3):
    df_new = df[df['col'] == i]
```

but this does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially with this for loop you are overwriting `df` and since the first and second conditions can't be applied simultaneously, you will end with an empty dataframe.

You could create them dynamically within a dictionary, where the key is the name of the dataframe and the value the filtered dataframe. Try with:

```
dfs = {}
for i in range(3):
   dfs["df_"+str(i)] = df[df['col'] == i]
```

This will generate a dictionary that looks like the following structure:

```
{df_1:df[df['col']==1],
 df_2:df[df['col']==2]}
```

And you can access them via its key name `dfs['df_1']`

Comment: Ah wait, that is a mistake from my part. I am creating the new df from another one. I will edit my original post. It just doesn't seem to iterate over i.

Comment: After your reviewing the edit, the same issue applies, the variable is being overwritten after each iteration.

Comment: if I do it for just 1 (`range(1)`) iteration it also does not do anything. It's fine if it gets overwritten, its for a larger function, but it just doesnt do anything.

Comment: The slicing is correct, are you sure `col` is of numeric type and not string or object? `'1' != 1`

Comment: Yeah, if I just type `df[df['col'] == 1]` then I get the full df as required

Comment: I will add a reproducible sample

Comment: Yes, please add the first couple of rows in your dataframe.